# trying to get data from different queries to render on page using promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, promise

I tried to do something like below. The problem is `console.log(reviews)` outputs `undefind` I wanted it to be defined so I could use it in the render. It's probably undefined because the variable doesn't get set because of asynchronous activities.

```
app.get("/company/:comp", checkIfAuthed , function(req,res){

    var reviews;
    Reviews.find({companyName : req.params.comp}).exec()
    .then(function(reviews){
        reviews = reviews;
        return Comps.findOne({name : req.params.comp}).exec();
    })
    .then(function(comp){
        console.log(reviews)
         res.render("indivComp", {authed :app.locals.authed, user : app.locals.user, comp : comp, reviews : reviews})
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is you have `reviews` inside the .then as a parameter, which means the outer `reviews` var is masked by the parameter ... change the parameter name to something else, e.g. `x`, then change the next line `reviews = x;`

```
app.get("/company/:comp", checkIfAuthed , function(req,res){

    var reviews;
    Reviews.find({companyName : req.params.comp}).exec()
    .then(function(x){
        reviews = x;
        return Comps.findOne({name : req.params.comp}).exec();
    })
    .then(function(comp){
        console.log(reviews)
         res.render("indivComp", {authed :app.locals.authed, user : app.locals.user, comp : comp, reviews : reviews})
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need both promises to complete before your code does it's thing. You can use

`Promise.all([promise1(), promise2()]).then(function (obj) {});`

`obj` will contain an array of your responses in the order in which they were recieved. So, `obj[0]` will be the result of `promise1` and `obj[1]` would be the result of `promise2`. From there, you should have data from both responses and you can do what you want with it.

This is how you can do it using angular but the same concept applies in a non-angular solution:

```
$scope.p1 = function () {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/some/url'
    });
}

$scope.p2 = function () {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/some/url'
    });
}

$q.all([p1(), p2()]).then(function (obj) {
    var p1Response = obj[0];
    var p2Response = obj[1];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your code

```
app.get("/company/:comp", checkIfAuthed , function(req,res){

var reviews;
Reviews.find({companyName : req.params.comp}).exec()
.then(function(reviews){
    reviews = reviews;
    return Comps.findOne({name : req.params.comp}).exec();
})
.then(function(comp){
    console.log(reviews)
     res.render("indivComp", {authed :app.locals.authed, user : app.locals.user, comp : comp, reviews : reviews})
    })
})
```

The problem is an issue of scoping

```
 reviews = reviews; // references itself in that scope
```

Does not change the upper scope of

```
 var reviews; // remains undefined
```

Therefore

```
 console.log(reviews); // Accesses the upper function scope and to search and finds var reviews which is undefined
```

So as @jaromanda-x suggests change the the first function parameter

```
 .then(function(reviews){
     reviews = reviews;
     return Comps.findOne({name : req.params.comp}).exec();
  })
```

I'll suggest:

```
 .then(function(receivedReviews){
      reviews = receivedReviews;
      return Comps.findOne({name : req.params.comp}).exec();
  })
```

verbose, but more explicit!
Apparently it was not asyc problem, but scope problem. Cheers!